Issue with monitor settings after installing Ubuntu 24.04
This old desktop machine (Dell Inspiron 530 from around 2008, 64 bits, 3 GB RAM) was still running Ubuntu 16.04 until today, and it was working fine (dual boot).
Today I tried to install Ubuntu 24.04 on a different partition: the installation went ok, but after the reboot the monitor resolution was totally messed up, whether booting on the new 24.04 partition, the old 16.04 partition or apparently even a Boot Repair Disk USB.

The consequences were different (seemingly random): sometimes I had an error message "analog input cannot display this video mode"; sometimes I was able to login but did not have access to the taskbar on the left or the top bar; ...
I tried starting the kernel with nomodeset, and it was usually working better but still rarely working. In particular I was able to reach the display setting in the old 16.04 partition, but it would not let me select the correct resolution.

I'm very confused by this issue, especially the fact that the monitor was working fine with Ubuntu 16.04 so far, so why is nothing working now? Something must have been modified by the 24.04 installation, right? What is it and can I fix the display issue?

I'm fine with going back to using the old 16.04 partition
in case it matters, the monitor is a Dell 22 inches from around 2008 as well. I don't have another monitor available to switch.


Update: the next day the computer was able to start with the correct resolution for the old 16.04 partition. So apparently the problem was solved, albeit as mysteriously as it appeared  (to me at least). I leave the question open in case anybody can enlighten me about this issue, but technically the problem is solved (I give up on 24.04 for this computer, it's not worth the trouble).
